# Why would a function that returns a Result always return Err?

Tags: rust

I ran across [the `missing_field` function](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/d1205393109c474201985907ae0077afa87bc81d/serde/src/de/mod.rs#L766) while looking through the [Serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) source:

```
/// Report that the struct has a field that wasn't deserialized
fn missing_field<V>(&mut self, field: &'static str) -> Result<V, Self::Error>
    where V: Deserialize,
{
    Err(Error::missing_field(field))
}
```

Why is this useful? Why return a `Result` if it will unconditionally be `Err`?

Comment: Are you asking why it always returns an error or why it was declared as returning a result?

Comment: Both, I guess.  Why return a `Result` if it will be `Err`, unconditionally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you aren't including the context of the function:

```
pub trait MapVisitor {

    // ...

    fn missing_field<V>(&mut self, field: &'static str) -> Result<V, Self::Error>
        where V: Deserialize,
    {
        Err(Error::missing_field(field))
    }
}
```

This is a [*default trait method*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/traits.html#default-methods). Every type that implements this trait will get this method for free if they do nothing special, but may choose to reimplement it instead. Presumably most implementations will not implement the method, but it may also just be a sane default.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shepmaster answered, this is just a default for data formats in which a missing field is always an error.

There are data formats in which a missing field is not always an error. JSON is one common example. A struct like the following:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct S {
    a: i32,
    b: Option<i32>,
}
```

can be deserialized from the JSON string `{"a":0}` in which the field "b" is missing. The Serde Deserializer for JSON defines a missing Option field to mean `Option::None`.

[Here is JSON's implementation of `missing_field`.](https://github.com/serde-rs/json/blob/ccb6e44a6dda9fd2bf21361560ab97962478cfc5/json/src/de.rs#L813-L877)